# vim 8.0 e353: nothing in register "

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using vim version 8.0.1453 on Ubuntu 18.04 Server and getting error **e353: nothing in register "** always when I try to paste yanked text after closing and reopening the file. Yanking and pasting inside the same file works as long as I don't close the file. After reopening the file I tried to run :reg but it returns an empty list of registers.

I'm using vim inside tmux and I have another system with the exact same vim and tmux versions and everything works. I have deleted my .vimrc and .vim folder to isolate the problem.

I have already tried all suggestions that I could find using Google, but nothing seems to help. I have uninstalled all vim versions and reinstalled vim from the ubuntu repository. I also tried and it turns out that this works in neovim but not regular vim.

Comment: Could you clarify if the working system has the same vim configuration as the problematic one? I believe that the behaviour you describe is the default for vim, and you need to add configuration for this to work.

Comment: By *"closing and reopening the file"*, do you mean quitting Vim and starting it again? If so, what does `:set viminfo?` return? Do you have a `.viminfo` file in your home directory?

Comment: @filbranden Thaks, you solved my problem!!! I was doing a `cat .viminfo` and getting Permission denied. After chown to my user from root the copy-paste started working! I didn't even notice the existence of the .viminfo file before and didn't have a look at its permissions earlier.

Comment: @AirPett I'll post that as an answer then. Glad to know you've solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your `~/.viminfo` file is properly configured and have the right permissions.

That's the file where Vim saves registers at the end of an editing session, so if it can't write to it, it won't be able to restore the registers when starting a new instance.

See also `:set viminfo?` and `:help 'viminfo'` for the setting on what gets saved and how much gets saved to the `~/.viminfo` file, there are limits there that could be causing an issue similar to the one you described.